# When to use shallow fetch different from 1

Tags: git, continuous-integration, vnext

I see the idea to use Shallow Fetch when getting source in a CI build, as it only get the latest revision of every file.

But I'm more in doubt when to have several revisions.

When do you use Shallow Fetch > 1 or not using it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When do you use Shallow Fetch > 1 or not using it at all?

When you need the history topology to do the thing you want to do in your build.

For example, some use `git describe` or calculate the numbers of commit since the last tag to generate a semantic versioning version number.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. :-)